# Disable search-as-you-type in Doom Emacs

Tags: search, doom, pdf-tools

Is there a way to disable "search as you type" functionality in Doom Emacs? Either with the Vim equivalent of `/` or through I-search `C-s`. With large documents, that functionality causes Emacs to hang fatally.